# execute stored proc in ExecuteStoreQuery EF. is this a bug in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

trying to execute the stored proc in EF using the following code:

```
var params = new object[] {new SqlParameter("@FirstName", "Bob")};
return this._repositoryContext.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResultType>("GetByName", params);
```

but keep getting this error:

> Procedure or function 'GetByName' expects parameter '@FirstName',
>   which was not supplied.

and from sql profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'GetByName',N'@FirstName nvarchar(100),@FirstName=N'Bob'
```

what is wrong wit the above ExecuteStoreQuery code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that `params` is a reserved word...

Think your query needs to be:

```
var params = new object[] {new SqlParameter("@FirstName", "Bob")};
return this._repositoryContext.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResultType>("exec GetByName @FirstName", params);
```

Should also say that if that proc is a standard part of your database and data model then you should [import it into your EDM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx) so it's available directly on your context.

Comment: how can i achieve it using ExecuteStoreQuery method? i have no control of what sql statement is going to be generated. it is totally upto ExecuteStoreQuery method.

Comment: thanks mate.. the word "exec" is optional. tested with return this._repositoryContext.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResultType>("GetByName @FirstName", params) and works ok!

Answer (score 3):

Use the ExecuteFunction instead of ExecuteStoreQuery which is more suitable for the "ad-hoc" queries.

```
var parameters = new ObjectParameter[] {new ObjectParameter("FirstName", "Bob")};
return this._repositoryContext.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<ResultType>("GetByName", parameters);
```

The stored procedures can also be mapped as function in the context and thus can be used as typed method. Take a look at [Using stored procedures with Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/03/01/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to use a SP in EF, if you have multiple parameters:-

```
        public virtual ObjectResult<GetEpisodeCountByPracticeId_Result> GetEpisodeCountByPracticeId(Nullable<int> practiceId, Nullable<System.DateTime> dat1)
    {

        SqlParameter practiceIdParameter = practiceId.HasValue ?
            new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "practiceId", Value = practiceId, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int } :
            new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "practiceId", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int }; 

        SqlParameter dat1Parameter = dat1.HasValue ?
            new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "dat1", Value = dat1, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime }:
            new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "dat1", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime }; 


        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<GetEpisodeCountByPracticeId_Result>("exec GetEpisodeCountByPracticeId @practiceId, @dat1", practiceIdParameter, dat1Parameter);
    }
```

If you dont add the parameters (e.g. @practiceId) in the commandText property then you get the error you received